# custom variance R function gives me NA

Tags: r, variance

I'm new in R and I can't figure out why do I get NA :

```
get_vr <- function(vector){
  vr = 0
  for(i in 1:8435){
    vr <- vr + (vector[i]-vector[i+1])^2
  }
  return(vr)
}
x <- get_vr(vol)
x
```

(length(vol) gives 8436)

vol looks like this:

```
> vol
   [1] 35222060874 29893183716 30934096509 30835736946 25922656496 29432489719 32378792851 30682598115 34398744403
  [10] 28647338393 22177678796 19647331549 24397913026 25770680779 22600204051 24097418512 26422375678 34217320471
```

this is the output:

```
> get_var <- function(vector){
+   var = 0
+   for(i in 1:8435){
+     var <- var + (vector[i]-vector[i+1])^2
+   }
+   return(var)
+ }
> x <- get_var(vol)
> x
[1] NA
```

Comment: If the length of `vol` is 8435, then your `vector[i+1]` will return `NA` because it is indexing beyond the length of `vector`. Is there a reason you are (1) hard-coding 8435, I suggest instead `for (i in seq_along(vector)[-1])`, and using `vector[i-1]-vector[i]`; and (2) `for`-looping this instead of R-idiomatic vectorized math? I suggest `vr <- diff(vector)^2`. (And ... this is not "variance" in the classical sense, unless I'm missing something significant.)

Comment: Indeed, I'm not looking for the classical sense of variance
I tried using
if (i != length(array))  to avoid going beyond the length of the vector but got:
Error in if (i != length(array)) { : 
  valeur manquante là où TRUE / FALSE est requis
"missing value where TRUE/FALSE is required"
I hardcoded 8435 because it's 1 below the length of the vector (the last [i+1] will be the last value of the vector

Comment: Well ... your variable is named `vector` but you tried `length(array)`, is that a typo? Instead of checking `if (i != length(vector))`, it's much better to never get there in the first place, using the correct `seq_len` or other sequence to begin with.

Comment: length(vol) is supposed to be the number of items in vol.
I got an error when trying to iterate on every item using a function so I hardcoded 8435 because it's one item below the length of the vector so vol[i+1] doesn't give me index out of bound.
I didn't know about the seq_len function until now

Comment: As mentioned by @r2evans `sum(diff(vol)^2)` or (`-sum(diff(vol)^2)`) should give you what you are looking for without the `for` loop.